# Detect a broken internet connection using windows batch programming

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm using an internet connection which goes down after some time. If I repair my connection it works fine. I have to do it always manually. I want to do this task automatically.

I.e. I want to create a windows batch file which is constantly running in the background. When my internet connection is down, it will renew and restart the connection again without any interaction

I want to do this task using a windows batch file. I tried this:

```
runas /user:local\administrator
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
```

However, I don't know how to detect whether Network connection is down or up?

I'm hoping for quick and positive response.

Comment: to start with SO provides you enough memory to expand and type your words bt for but
hv for have etc. So it would be better if you can edit your question

Comment: Network connection or Internet connection?  The two are vastly different, one you can monitor the interfaces, the second requires interacting with a known reliable target in the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and ping a widely used service in your country (or ping google like crazy) to detect internet connectivity. it's not bullet proof, but will let you know when your internet is down (probably).

The result of pinging could be checked by batch/script and according to the result, decide whether you want to `ipconfig /renew` or not.

Comment: yeah same logic .. i hv decided to go with bt .. how to chk the results of ping .. is request time out .. 
and i don't want to renew connectin of 1 request time out .
if der r 10 request time out in ping results then do the renew . bt i want to implement it using code .. ... help plzz

Comment: all I have for you are some pointers:
you can run `ping` with -n to tell it how many times to try, and redirect the output to a file.

you can use `for` in batch files to process the output file (more specifically `for /f`) and tell if you have timeouts or successful pings.

Comment: @ECHO OFF
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ECHO.
ECHO LAN IP REPAIRED.
ECHO.
PAUSE
CLS
EXIT

I hv written .. this .. bt i don't know how to detect Request time out .. then only i want to call this batch file.

Comment: as I pointed out in my comment above, try `ping` redirected to a file, then have a read about in `help for`

Answer (score 1):

I made this some time ago. I think that will help you. (but in is spanish)

https://github.com/edgardok/Arregla_Internet/blob/master/ARREGLA.INTERNET.bat

```
:INICIO
IF EXIST respuesta.tmp DEL respuesta.tmp >nul

PING %DIRECCIONREMOTA% > respuesta.tmp
FIND /C /I "perdidos = 0" respuesta.tmp >nul
GOTO CASO%ERRORLEVEL%

:CASO1
REM ***conexion fallida***

ECHO %date% %time%.  NO ESTA HABILITADA LA PLACA DE RED O NO FUNCIONA.
GOTO menu

:CASO0
REM ***conexion OK***
ECHO %date% %time%.  Conexion ok.
GOTO menu
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you must be trying to address is

**Why your network connection is breaking after sometime**

and not

**How to repair your network connection every now and then**

because if you are able to identify the root cause for first problem then you are done.

Comment: no I just want to know how to repair connection only when its down using batch file windows .. 

Why my network conn is down .. its nt always bt sumtimes.. it happens

Answer (score -1):

f 'r sng Wndws  r bv,  cn tr ths:

```
fcnfg | grp -c "P ddrss"
```

Ths wll gv  th nmbr f mtchng P drsss - n cs r cnnctn s dwn, 'll hv fwr thn nrmll.

'll nd `grp` fr ths (s t's nt  prt f Wndws), bt t cn b btnd frm ths RL: [nxtls.srcfrg.nt](http://nxtls.srcfrg.nt)

Comment: Your keyboard apparently does not possess vowels?

Comment: Indeed. This was an attempt to match the style of the question - in hope that by doing so, it would be more understandable to the asker ;)